# How to make text in a WinForms TextBox unselectable without disabling it?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Is it possible to make the text in a TextBox unselectable without disabling the TextBox?
It's a RichTextBox and I need it's formatting and selection features.
I can't disable it because I want to handle MouseMove and MouseDown events.

So far I've thought about disabling the Text box and putting a panel on top of it which will delegate it's events to the textbox handlers, but I can't make the panel transparent so it hides the textbox.

Thanks.

Comment: you got me confused because you want its selection feature and you want it unselectable? what do you mean by "unselectable"?

Comment: If this is a crude attempt at preventing the user from copy-and-pasting the content, it will not work *and* it will make a lot of users hate your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about dealing with the .Enter or .GotFocus events to clear any selection made?
You can see the opposite of what you wanted in [Automatically select all text on focus in WinForms TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97459/automatically-select-all-text-on-focus-in-winforms-textbox).

Comment: Thanks, I just caught the enter event and set the focus to another control.

Comment: You do know that that's not advisable!  It clearly states in the documentation [MSDN, Control Focus Events] that you should not set focus from within Enter, GotFocus, Leave, LostFocus, Validating, or Validated event handlers.  At least, that's how I read it!

Source:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx

Answer (score 2):

How about handling selection change event like this:

```
    private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = this.richTextBox1.Text.Length;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're getting at (wanting something unselectable but wanting its selection features), but does setting `ReadOnly` to true accomplish what you're looking for?

Comment: I select specific words programmaticly, but I don't want the user to be able to select anything.

Comment: Ah. Makes sense now. Go with what nahmiasdror suggested in that case. The user can still affect the selection in ReadOnly mode.