# c# make textbox unselectable

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I want to get the same functionality as `Textbox.Enabled = false;` so that the text in a textbox is not selectable at all but without the text changing to light gray. It should stay the same.

`Textbox.ReadOnly = true;` still lets you select it so that's not good.

And no it has to be a textbox not a label unfortunately.

Comment: Is this for a webforms or winforms app?

Comment: Please see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/249448d3-418e-41ce-9e5a-1f311890e78b/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276179/how-to-change-the-font-color-of-a-disabled-textbox.  This is a duplicate.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Have you tried: Textbox.Forecolor="Black"; ?

Comment: First try to find your answer here before posting a new question.

Comment: winforms, I forgot to mention, sorry. and yes Textbox.Forecolor="Black"; does not change the colour, have tried it.

Comment: Fine your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276179/how-to-change-the-font-color-of-a-disabled-textbox

Comment: Other possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/411143/266919

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this in WPF? If so you should use Textbox.Enabled = false; and change the styling so that this disabled textbox looks the way you want it to look.

Comment: yes it's weird though as if I set `textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;` works just fine but `textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;` does not. Not sure why

Comment: It also works on WinForms