# Select Text from TextBox in Click event

Tags: c#, events, select, properties

That you can follow me, it's the best you create a small application containing the following code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    textBox1.Text = "Any Text";
    textBox1.Click += delegate
                            {
                                textBox1.Select(0, 0);
                            };
}

private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    linkLabel1.Focus();
}
```

The `linkLabel1` is only there that you can leave the focus from the `textBox1`.

And now, just click on the `textBox`.
The `Select` Method works and the first position of the Text is selected.
The problem is, first the clicked position is selected. Just for a short time but still pretty annoying.

I already tried `this.SuspendLayout()` in the `GotFocus` Event (because this gets fired before Click) and `this.ResumeLayout()` in the Click Event, but no success.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Try using your own class that is derived from TextBox.  Then override OnClick and do what you want.  If you do this, then the default OnClick behavior will not occur.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically select all text on focus in WinForms TextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97459/automatically-select-all-text-on-focus-in-winforms-textbox)

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I don't want to select all text. Read it again.

Comment: @Andy, obviously, but you could easily infer that you don't need to issue a `SelectAll` but rather `Select` -so please think a bit more abstractly. The answer to that question resolved the quirky nature of the text box and selection.

Comment: @Mike Very good idea but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I tried it but didn't work. Looked exactly the same.

Comment: Try overriding OnMouseDown and OnMouseUp?  See if you can isolate where the default selection is being done.  This might work if don't ever want the default mouse up, down, click, etc. behavior.

Comment: @Mike Thank you very much. Added your suggestions as answer. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much **Mike**.

I figured it out through creating a class deriving from `TextBox` and overriding `OnMouseDown`:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.Select(0, 0);

    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
```

Works perfectly now!

Comment: Wait, shouldn't it be "Select(0, 0)"?

Comment: @KappaG3 Of course, you're right. Typed it correct in code but wrong here. Thanks for telling!