# Clicking on TextBox inside Panel triggers Enter event multiple times

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, textbox, panel

I have some TextBoxes inside some panels. For those textboxes I set up an Enter event function.

```
private void TextBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tBox = sender as TextBox;
    tBox.HideSelection = false;
    tBox.SelectAll();
    tBox.HideSelection = true;
}
```

I do this so the user can tab into or click a textbox and start typing. Now, I've done this in other forms successfully. My problem now is that, for some reason, putting them into a panel screws with the Enter event.

Inserting a break point into the code showed me that the event gets triggered multiple times, somewhere in the 20s or 30s. I also have a Leave event for them, but that doesn't get triggered, solely the Enter event. This only happens when they are inside the panel.

The TextBoxes are set to be TabStops and have different TabIndex.

Now, I do know *what* is causing it, but not why. If I remove the `tBox.HideSelection` I am able to enter the TextBox without triggering the Enter event multiple times. Not sure why the code gets screwed up in the Panel as, again, the codes works just as intended outside of said panel.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is that important to be care about **hideselection** ? .. why not just tBox.SelectAll ?

Comment: @matzone he wants to Select all the textbox text not only by switching tab but also by clicking on the textbox. I've tried the code and when clicking on the textbox, the text is not selected if there is only SelectAll().

Comment: @GarryVass No I haven't set the Handled property. EventArgs doesn't have a Handled property like KeyEventArgs. How would I do that with just EventArgs?

Comment: @matzone like king mentioned, `SelectAll()` doesn't seem highlight the text without `HideSelection = false`. I also have `HideSelection = true` at the end because it doesn't seem to let me tab out with out it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```
Dim lFocused as Boolean

Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.GotFocus
        TextBox1.SelectAll()
        lFocused = True
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
        lFocused = False
    End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseUp
    lFocused = True
    TextBox1.SelectAll()
End Sub
```

[Based idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97459/automatically-select-all-text-on-focus-in-winforms-textbox)

Comment: Well, as the code was, it got rid of the blinking and multiple triggers, but it didn't highlight the text. I did do some reworking of the code by removing the Enter event. I think problem was that the Enter event would go first and set LFocused to true, so when the mouse event checked it, it didn't do the selection. Anyway, I think the Enter event was not needed because when you tab into a TextBox, the text gets highlighted already so I only need to highlight when the mouse clicks on it.

Comment: @Natzely : I don't understand it because I already test it with VS 2005 and it worked .. and your textbox wont select.all the text if it got focus by mouse click .. but the code did !

Comment: I'm a little perplexed myself as to why SelectAll() works in the MouseUp event without the HideSelection, but not in Enter event.

Comment: I'll accept this answer as it does have the solution in it. The way I ended fixing this was moving the `tBox.SelectAll()` to the MouseClick event. All I have in the event is `TextBox tBox = sender as TextBox;` and `tBox.SelectAll();` and it seems to be doing its job. Thanks!