# SelectAll on enter to NumericUpDown control

Tags: vb.net

[There are people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97459/automatically-select-all-text-on-focus-in-winforms-textbox) which try to solve such problem on entering to textbox. And they solved that more or less successfully.
I am trying to do same thing with NumericUpDown control by subclassing it pretty unsuccessfully.
Here is my code:

```
Public Class xNumericUpDown
Inherits NumericUpDown

Private _focused As Boolean

Protected Overrides Sub OnEnter(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnEnter(e)
    If MouseButtons = MouseButtons.None Then
        Me.Select(0, Me.Text.Length)
        _focused = True
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnLeave(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLeave(e)
    _focused = False
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseUp(ByVal mevent As MouseEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseUp(mevent)
    If Not _focused Then
        If Me.Text.Length = 0 Then
            Me.Select(0, Me.Text.Length)
        End If
        _focused = True
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

This selects All by entering with keyboard but dont work when selecting control with mouse.

Any help with solving that problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably kick yourself, but try changing your code to this:

```
If Me.Text.Length > 0 Then
  Me.Select(0, Me.Text.Length)
End If
```

Comment: Well, at least I have to try... Thank you, I get it working with > 0!