# Is there a way to select all with one click in a textbox in c# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a number guessing game, and for convenience I would like to add a line of code to my program that selects all text within a text box with one click. I have tried everything I have found on here along with other trouble shooting sites I have found on google and none of it seems to work, even trying to force focus on the textbox. The textbox still behaves like a normal textbox, i.e. having to double click to select all.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace randomNumberGuessingGameFourthTry
{
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
         public Form1()
         {
          InitializeComponent();
         }

    private void startGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (min.Text == "" || min.Text == " " || min.Text == "Min")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You didn't enter a minimum value of zero or greater so the default value of 0 was set.");
            min.Text = "0";
        }

        if (max.Text == "" || max.Text == " " || max.Text == "Max")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You didn't enter a maximum value so the default value of 10 was set.");
            max.Text = "11";
        }

        startGuessing startGame = new startGuessing(min.Text, max.Text);
        this.Hide();
        startGame.ShowDialog();
    }

   private void exitGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void min_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        min.Focus();
        min.SelectAll();
        min.SelectionLength = min.Text.Length;

        int userInput1 = Convert.ToInt32(min.Text);
        if (!(userInput1 >= 0))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your min range must be at least 0 or higher", "Invalid range found");
        }
    }

    private void max_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        int userInput1 = Convert.ToInt32(min.Text);
        int userInput2 = Convert.ToInt32(max.Text);
        if (!(userInput2 <= userInput1 + 9))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your max range must be at least 10 digits higher than " + userInput1, "Invalid range found");
        }
    }
}
```

}

The above is the code for my form1.cs I figured if I could make it work here I could make it work on my second form in this program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should first call `SelectAll()` method then `Focus()`, not vice versa. This minimal example is working for me:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Click += TextBoxOnClick;
    }

    private void TextBoxOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox) sender;
        textBox.SelectAll();
        textBox.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that. I don't know if im implementing it incorrectly or if my program is just simply ignoring the code

Comment: @SubZero did you use Textbox.Click event? I have updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, that worked exactly like I wanted it too. I was missing the "textBox1.Click += TextBoxOnClick;" line up top when I was trying to implement select all in the past.

Answer (score 0):

What did you try?

The following works fine for me:

```
private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

    textBox.SelectAll();
}
```

Naturally, you need to add `textBox1_Click()` as an event handler for your `TextBox`'s `Click` event.

Note that the above will cause the text to *always* be completely selected with any mouse click in the control. This will make it impossible to select portions of the text using the mouse. If you want a more sophisticated behavior, you can use the answers found here:

[Making a WinForms TextBox behave like your browser's address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/97459)

Comment: I believe I have tried that too. But just to be sure since one of the text boxes in my code is named min I would implement your code by switching everything in your snippet with "textBox1" to "min" correct?

Comment: @Sub: the name of the method can be anything you want. If your `TextBox` name is `min`, then you might prefer the method to be named `min_Click()`, but it will work regardless. The code I posted doesn't depend on any specific control name, and can in fact be used with more than one `TextBox` in your form if you like. You just have to make sure you actually add the method as a handler for the `Click` event (either subscribe explicitly in your form's constructor, or use the Designer to set the handler in the `TextBox`'s properties window).