# Program selects textbox text on click, how to prevent subsequent clicks from selecting text again

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have multiple text boxes in my windows form whose text I want to become selected when they are clicked on by the user. I am trying to find a way to make only the first click in a box select text when the user makes consecutive clicks in the box. I would like to have subsequent clicks in the same box position a text cursor box rather than endlessly select the text, which is what is happening now.

I have tried calling focused.Select() inside an if statement that only runs if no text is already selected like shown below. The problem with that is that right after a user clicks on selected text briefly "un-selects" then Highlight_OnClick runs and the text is again selected.

```
    private void HighlightWhenFocused(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (sender is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox focused = sender as TextBox;
            focused.Select(0, focused.Text.Length);
            //if (focused.SelectionLength == 0 { focused.Select(0, focused.Text.Length); }    
            // does not work either
        }
    }
```

My code above always selects the text but the problem is that even once the user has clicked on a text box that is already selected, subsequent clicks only re-select the text.

Comment: Handle `Enter` event and then inside the event handler `BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll()));`

Comment: In the linked post, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6857301/3110834).

Answer (score 2):

You sound like you have bound this event handler to the Click event on the Textboxes.  You should use the `Enter` event instead.  This will fire once when the control is focused, but subsequent clicks will not re-trigger:

[image]

Comment: this event is actually bound to the Enter event as well, this allows me to use Tab to select the boxes, clicking on a textbox does not focus it and even if I changed that I would still have the same problem. Thanks for the suggestion!